# Applications not working

Tags: applications

Device: Samsung Galaxy Note 2 - GT-N7100 - Android Kitkat 4.4.2

This problem has been going on for some time. I factory reset the phone and reinstalled all apps. But the problem is recurring. "Unfortunately, Clock has stopped working".

[image: Application Manager error]
<sup>Application Manager error (click image for larger variant)</sup>

This is how the apps show in the Application manager. This happens over time with all the apps.

Sometimes, the phone suddenly stops working and restarts itself. During this time, it also wipes out all cache information from all apps.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered re-flashing the stock firmware with Odin? Might be the easiest option if you don't fear missing data :P